# Wireless Driver for Ubuntu 14.04 2012 macbook pro 13.3 (unibody)

Tags: wireless, drivers, 14.04, macbook

Yesterday, I finally was able to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my mid-2012 macbook pro 13.3in (NON-retina). I'm very new to this and I'm not sure how to get the wireless driver. I've already gone through a lot of Ubuntu's resources and I'm still lost. Any advice?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh and another note. For whatever reason, I'm not able to get an ethernet connection on Mac OSX or Ubuntu. I do however have a wireless connection on OSX